# Linux: How to find - without du or find - the largest or fastest-growing file or directory on a disk?

Tags: disk-space-utilization

Every so often one or other of our servers will announce that it's at 90% disk capacity, and we go to run some variant of 'du' on it, to drill down and find what's so big or what's growing quickly, and of course that takes more and more time on larger and larger disks.

Of course we can run du nightly, but these issues tend to happen explosively. :)

Are there any filesystems with support for tackling this without having to scan the whole disk? Perhaps a daemon that monitors file activity to maintain a fine-grained usage tree, or 'largest files' list or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no real alternative to using tools that scan the complete file system to find current disk hogs. Directory meta-data simply doesn't hold enough information about their children and children's children to avoid scanning all sub-directories and files individually and creating a disk usage tally.

## `du` avoidance strategies

**`Check open file descriptors`**
Often a first level of approach and assumption is that a single large file being written is the culprit, you can restrict your search to files that are currently open and only check the size of those.

For a detailed approach using `lsof`  see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/382693/48232

Something similar would be `du -sL  /proc/*/fd/* |sort -n` and then following the most interesting file descriptor links:

```
du -sL  /proc/*/fd/* |sort -n  
...
6344    /proc/873/fd/11
6344    /proc/873/fd/12
6344    /proc/873/fd/13
20140   /proc/359/fd/62
2028890 /proc/876/fd/6

ls -l /proc/876/fd/6

lrwx------. 1 root root 64 Sep  8 10:09 /proc/876/fd/6 -> /var/log/httpd/example.net_access_log
```

**`iotop`**
And similar IO monitoring allows you to identify the process(es) generating the most IO. Once you have the `PID` you can run `ls -l /proc/[PID]/fd/*` and see where exactly the process is writing to. This allows you to identify current active processes that may be writing many smaller files rather than a single large file.

**`Quota`**
Not fashionable anymore and your mileage may vary, but enabling quota on file systems (beforehand) has several potential advantages.

- set hard- and soft-quota limits and the offending run-away user/process will be halted before completely filling up the file-system and impeding other users/processes
- even with unlimited quota set, disk quota reporting is a quick and easy way to determine who, which user/group ID's are the disk hogs.

**`Partitioning`**
Although a PITA in other regards setting users/applications up with their own volume/partition/filesystem(s) rather than using only a single root file-system allows you to run the quick `df` which limits the amount of searching you need to do.

## Quick(er) disk usage insights

Rather than running `du  --max-depth=2  <some-filesystem> | sort -n` or similar (which due to the `|` pipe only shows results *after* the complete file system has been scanned) I typically run

```
du  --max-depth=2  <some-filesystem> | tee /tmp/du.txt
```

in one window and in another:

```
watch -n 1 "sort -nr < /tmp/du.txt"
```

which has the advantage that you get to see some immediate progress.

### `ncdu`

For me the `du` command  is often useful enough,  it is always installed  and more expedient than for example the **venerable [`ncdu`](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu)** , which first needs to build the disk usage cache before presenting you with the admittedly nice and useful navigation TUI that allows you to drill down to the largest directories.

[image: ncdu - TUI disk usage browser]

### `duc`

Debian and Ubuntu come with optional **[`duc`](https://duc.zevv.nl/)** that still requires you to do an (initial) full-scan of a directory tree / file-system but which also persists that disk usage cache. `duc` also allows updating that existing disk usage cache, which should be quicker for subsequent runs.

The TUI interface is similar to `ncdu` but the full GUI offers some really nice usage diagrams. Demo: https://duc.zevv.nl/demo.cgi?x=338&y=181&path=/

[image: https://duc.zevv.nl/img/example.png]

Comment: Thanks - that's a really helpful list of strategies, and I'd never thought to scan file descriptors as a substitute for lsof. The unlimited quota idea is clever, though not immediately applicable for my situation as it's usually things running as root (though we could look into migrating them to real users).